# import json file to mongodb without '[' causes error

Tags: json, mongodb, import

```
mongoimport --db my_db --collection mycol --file "D:\workspace\intelligent_TDR\charm\employees.json" --jsonArray
```

Importing the employees.json file using the above command gives me the error

```
Failed: error reading separator after document #1: bad JSON array format - found no opening bracket '[' in input source
```

The content of json file is

```
{"employees":[
  { "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
  { "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" },
  { "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones" }
]}
```

If I place the content within '[' and ']' the import works.

The below json is imported without error

```
[{"employees":[
  { "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
  { "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" },
  { "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones" }
]}]
```

Comment: Why do you use the `--jsonArray` option if you don't have an array as your input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the json file you can pass the documents like,

```
{"employees":
  { "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
  { "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" },
  { "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones" }
}
```

It is not required to give the documents as a list.